# How can I subtract a multiset from a set with a given multiset?

Tags: set, logic, isabelle, multiset

So I'm trying to define a function `apply_C :: "('a multiset ⇒ 'a option) ⇒ 'a multiset ⇒ 'a multiset"`

It takes in a function `C` that may convert an `'a multiset` into a single element of type `'a`. Here we assume that each element in the domain of `C` is pairwise mutually exclusive and not the empty multiset (I already have another function that checks these things). `apply` will also take another multiset `inp`. What I'd like the function to do is check if there is at least one element in the domain of `C` that is completely contained in `inp`. If this is the case, then perform a set difference `inp - s` where `s` is the element in the domain of `C` and add the element `the (C s)` into this resulting multiset. Afterwards, keep running the function until there are no more elements in the domain of `C` that are completely contained in the given `inp` multiset.

What I tried was the following:

```
fun apply_C :: "('a multiset ⇒ 'a option) ⇒ 'a multiset ⇒ 'a multiset" where
"apply_C C inp = (if ∃s ∈ (domain C). s ⊆# inp then apply_C C (add_mset (the (C s)) (inp - s)) else inp)"
```

However, I get this error:

```
Variable "s" occurs on right hand side only:
⋀C inp s.
   apply_C C inp =
   (if ∃s∈domain C. s ⊆# inp
    then apply_C C
          (add_mset (the (C s)) (inp - s))
    else inp)
```

I have been thinking about this problem for days now, and I haven't been able to find a way to implement this functionality in Isabelle. Could I please have some help?

Comment: Just to clear this up, are you saying that `apply_C` will only be called with values for `C` such that `domain C` has at most one element? In that case, you can use `the_elem (domain C)` to get access to that `s`. Otherwise this is not well-defined because there can be multiple different values of `s` that give different results. You could pick one of them by writing `SOME s. s ∈ domain C` in that case. However, `SOME` is not executable; `the_elem` is.

Comment: @ManuelEberl `domain C` may have more than one element. Also, since each element in `domain C` is mutually exclusive, no matter which order you apply each rule in `C`, the resulting output will always be the same. I think you can imagine it like algebraic simplification with numbers. No matter which order you perform the same set of manipulations, the resulting simplified form will always be the same.

Comment: I don't see how this can be deterministic without considering some kind of order on the elements and forbidding the empty set. Take `C = {#} ->  0, {#a#} ->  1, {#a, b#} -> 2`. What should `apply_C C {#a,b#}`   return?

Comment: Additionally, why does this function terminate? take `C = (%x. case x of {#a#} -> Some a | _ => None)` (not isabelle syntax) and `apply_C C {#a#}`. According to your definition, it does not terminate…

Comment: @MathiasFleury I think I did say in the question that all elements in the domain of `C` are pairwise mutually exclusive. So you can see that your example of `C` is not valid since `{#a#}` and `{#a,b#}` has a nonempty intersection. However, I did forget to say that no element should be the empty multiset, so I should edit my question. Finally, this function should terminate because none of the elements in the domain are the empty multiset and the input set gets smaller every time the function is run on it recursively. Unfortunately, I am not proficient at Isabelle so the syntax/method is wrong.

Comment: @MathiasFleury So for example, if `C = {#a,b#} -> c, {#d,e,f#} -> g` and I try to perform `apply_C C {#a,a,a,a,a,b,b,d,d,d,d,e,e,f,#}` I should expect `{# a,a,a,c,c,d,d,d,e,g#}` as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking more about it, I don't believe there is a simple solutions for that Isabelle.

## Do you need that?

I have not said why you want that. Maybe you can reduce your assumptions? Do you really need a function to calculate the result?

## How to express the definition?

I would use an inductive predicate that express one step of rewriting and prove that the solution is unique. Something along:

```
context
  fixes C :: ‹'a multiset ⇒ 'a option›
begin
inductive apply_CI where
 ‹apply_CI (M + M') (add_mset (the (C M)) M')›
if ‹M ∈ dom C›

context
  assumes
     distinct: ‹⋀a b. a ∈ dom C ⟹ b ∈ dom C ⟹ a ≠ b ⟹ a ∩# b = {#}› and
     strictly_smaller: ‹⋀a b. a ∈ dom C ⟹ size a > 1› 
begin

lemma apply_CI_determ:
  assumes
    ‹apply_CI⇧*⇧* M M⇩1› and
    ‹apply_CI⇧*⇧* M M⇩2› and
    ‹⋀M⇩3. ¬apply_CI M⇩1 M⇩3›
    ‹⋀M⇩3. ¬apply_CI M⇩2 M⇩3›
  shows ‹M⇩1 = M⇩2›
  sorry

lemma apply_CI_smaller:
  ‹apply_CI M M' ⟹ size M' ≤ size M›
  apply (induction rule: apply_CI.induct)
  subgoal for M M'
    using strictly_smaller[of M]
    by auto
  done

lemma wf_apply_CI:
   ‹wf {(x, y). apply_CI y x}›
(*trivial but very annoying because not enough useful lemmas on wf*)
  sorry
end
end
```

I have no clue how to prove `apply_CI_determ` (no idea if the conditions I wrote down are sufficient or not), but I did spend much thinking about it.

After that you can define your definitions with:

```
definition apply_C where
  ‹apply_C M = (SOME M'. apply_CI⇧*⇧* M M' ∧ (∀M⇩3. ¬apply_CI M' M⇩3))›
```

and prove the property in your definition.

## How to execute it

I don't see how to write an executable function on multisets directly. The problem you face is that one step of apply_C is nondeterministic.

If you can use lists instead of multisets, you get an order on the elements for free and you can use `subseqs` that gives you all possible subsets. Rewrite using the first element in subseqs that is in the domain of C. Iterate as long as there is any possible rewriting.

Link that to the inductive predicate to prove termination and that it calculates the right thing.

Remark that in general you cannot extract a list out of a multiset, but it is possible to do so in some cases (e.g., if you have a linorder over 'a).

Comment: I was recommended to use a function since the original model used a set of "element transitions" that looked something like `{a|b|c -> d, q|q|w -> f, ...}` which is essentially a partial mapping. However, on my own I found it wasn't easy to implement it and you've helped confirm that it's either not possible or messier than expected. Thank you so much!